# Fit figure and caption on one page

Tags: floats

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and trying to come to grips with it. I understand I can resize a figure to fit the column width or text height quite easily:

```
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]...
```

or

```
\includegraphics[height=.1\textheight]...
```

I was wondering if there is an easy way to get a figure and its caption to fit in a page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Do you only want to scale the figure or do you want to scale the font size of the caption too?

Comment: if the figure itself is fit to the `\textheight`, there won't be enough space for the caption.  nonetheless, if you put it into a float -- `\begin{figure][p]` -- it will stay together, but you will get a complaint that it's too large.  you might try to apply a scaling factor, e.g. `[scale=.8]`, instead of the height or width to get it to an acceptable size.

Answer (score 5):

Generally it's better really to design the figure to fit (or scale by a fixed amount) scaling arbitrary sized figures to fit the page means that each scales by a different amount so you get inconsistent font sizes in each figure.

However for when you need it you can go

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr \textheight - 4\baselineskip\relax]{myfig}
\caption{zzzz}
\end{figure}
```

assuming 4 lines worth of space is enough for your caption and its surrounding space.
Using `[p]` as clearly it can not fit on a text page if it is that big.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{figure*}[tb] 
\centering
 \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.9\paperwidth]{./fig/fig5.eps}}
\caption{The SAP data model based on an UML class diagram: classes and relationships.}
\label{fig:Fig5}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).